# Guest Entries required fields fatal error

Tags: guest-entries, comments

I've built a comment system using Guest Entries. If I set fields to be required and don't fill them in in the front-end, I get the following error.

`Fatal error: Class 'Craft\GuestEntriesEvent' not found in ****/craft/plugins/guestentries/controllers/GuestEntriesController.php on line 136`

New entries are set to disabled by default, I have tried with all fields set to required, and with only certain fields set to required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Guest Entries [1.5.1](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/releases/tag/1.5.1).